# What is the difference between Argon2d and Argon2i?

Tags: encryption, hash, complexity, argon2

I know that Argon2d accesses the memory array in a password dependent order and Argon2i accesses the memory array in a password independent order. What is the difference in computational complexity?

Comment: TL;DR: both _scale_ the same when it comes to the parameters, but Argon2d has better time-memory-trade-off resistance whereas Argon2i has better side-channel resistance.

Comment: Related: [Why use argon2i or argon2d if argon2id exists?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/48935/why-use-argon2i-or-argon2d-if-argon2id-exists)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As [@sejpm already hinted in his comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/53932/what-is-the-difference-between-argon2d-and-argon2i#comment119315_53932): ***both scale the same*** when it comes to the parameters.

You might still want to read [the RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-irtf-cfrg-argon2-03) to get the complete picture, but the general differences can be quickly summarized:

## Argon2i

Argon2i is invulnerable to side-channel timing attacks, but is weaker against time-memory trade-off (TMTO) attacks.

Argon2i uses data-independent memory access, which is preferred for things like password hashing and password-based key derivation.

## Argon2d

Argon2d is vulnerable to side-channel timing attacks, but offers the best resistance to TMTO attacks.

Argon2d uses data-depending memory access, which makes it more suitable for things like cryptocurrencies and proof-of-work (POW) applications with no threats from side-channel timing attacks.