# Why don't we use Blowfish if it hasn't been cracked?

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis, block-cipher, provable-security, blowfish

Since Blowfish is old, well-audited, and has no published attacks, why are we using AES instead? I know that Bruce Schneier said that Blowfish is insecure and told people to transition to Twofish, but why? AES has many vulnerabilities, such as padding oracle attacks and power-consumption analysis, but Blowfish doesn't have any well-known issues. And Blowfish can take a key up to 448 bits, which is larger than AES's 256 bits. Is there something I am not understanding? It's been under public scrutiny for the longest with the least issues.

Perhaps it is because of Blowfish's small block size?

**Context: Is it safe to use Blowfish to encrypt strings of less than 30 characters?**

Comment: Padding oracle attacks aren't specific to AES, and power-analysis attacks will likely work on most Blowfish implementations as well.

Comment: I've roll-back the edit. The question already had two answers and become an HNQ. What you edit is diverging the main course of the question. If you have a different question then you are free to ask another.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I didn't know about keeping questions on topic, although I probably should have :P

Comment: Once answered it is not a good action to diverge the question, as long as you may ask the answer(s) about that.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Why don't we use Blowfish if it hasn't been cracked?

The reason is well-known, it has 64-bit block size and therefore it is vulnerable to birthday attacks. This is done for HTTPS and for more information see [sweet32](https://sweet32.info/);

$$\text{Sweet32: Birthday attacks on 64-bit block ciphers in TLS and OpenVPN}
$$

> Is it safe to use Blowfish to encrypt strings of less than 30 characters?
> If I don't use it for HTTP, just for storing small strings, is it still insecure?

There is no problem. GnuPG made a [recommendation](https://web.archive.org/web/20171221180749/https://gnupg.org/faq/gnupg-faq.html#define_fish) for Blowfish;  Blowfish should not be used to encrypt files larger than 4Gb in size. If you want to use a block-cipher from Bruce Schneier use the successor, the Twofish algorithm, as [he said](https://web.archive.org/web/20161202063854/https://www.computerworld.com.au/article/46254/bruce_almighty_schneier_preaches_security_linux_faithful/?pp=3).

This recommendation 4GB makes $\approx 2^{33}$-bytes therefore, they recommended using at most $2^{30}$ blocks of encryption under the same key. With the birthday probability if you encrypt $2^{30}$ blocks you will have

$$(2^{30})^2/2^{64}/2 = 2^{60 - 64-1} = 1/2^{5}$$ probability of collision. This is still a high probability in the attacker's advantage.

---

**What is Sweet32 in short:**

The attack performed on the CBC mode of operation where the encryption is $$c_i = E_k(m_i \oplus c_{i-1})$$ wiht $c_{-1}$ is the nonce for the CBC.

Once one encrypts $2^{n/2}$ blocks with one key by the birthday attack we expect a collision on the ciphertext with 50% probability that can be observed by an eavesdropper. This means that $c_i = c_j$ with $i \neq j$ is observed. Since a block cipher is a fixed permutation under a key this implies that the inputs of $c_i$ and $c_j$ must be the same;

$$ m_i \oplus c_{i-1} = m_j \oplus c_{j-1}$$ with changing the side of the values we get $$m_i \oplus  m_j = c_{1-1} \oplus c_{j-1}.$$ That is the eavesdropper knows the x-or of the two message blocks.

---

**A short note padding oracles;**

Padding oracle is first described by  Serge Vaudenay in 2002;

- [Security Flaws Induced by CBC Padding Applications to SSL, IPSEC, WTLS](https://www.iacr.org/cryptodb/archive/2002/EUROCRYPT/2850/2850.pdf)

years later [real attacks are performed](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/76716/18298). Vaudenay applied it to RC5 in CBC mode, and it applies to any cipher that uses CBC mode as long as the server sends the padding-fail as an error. With the padding oracle attack, all messages can be revealed since it is a decryption oracle. Encrypt-than-Mac will prevent this attack.

---

**Update** for the [comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/87278/why-dont-we-use-blowfish-if-it-hasnt-been-cracked#comment191476_87286);

It turns out that OP has X/Y problem; the short string is a password then the obvious choice is the well-known solutions like the Argon2 which is the password hashing competition, winner. It has two modes;

- **Argon2d**: is faster and uses data-depending memory access. Data dependency immediately enables side-channel. This is suitable for cryptocurrencies and applications with no threats from side-channel attacks.
- **Argon2i**: uses data-independent memory access and this is preferred for password hashing and password-based key derivations.
- If you are not sure about which one to use then you can use the combined mode [Argon2id](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-irtf-cfrg-argon2-03#section-3.1).

Comment: Ok, that seems reasonable. If I don't use it for HTTP, just for storing small strings, is it still insecure?

Comment: Makes sense now, thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 7):

The biggest problem is the 64-bit block size already mentioned in kelalaka's answer, but Blowfish has a couple of other issues:

- It can't be implemented using the hardware AES acceleration found in many modern CPUs. While this is obviously unfair, it's a reality of the world right now and it's a factor in many people's choice of AES. The hardware instructions not only provide much higher throughput but also protect against side-channel attacks.
- It uses 4 KiB of S-boxes which depend on the key and are accessed in a data-dependent way on every round. I don't see how this could be protected against cache-timing attacks except by loading the tables in their entirety on every round, which would have terrible performance.

Blowfish's flexible key length is arguably a disadvantage, since it's an invitation to use a passphrase or other non-random secret directly as a key. This is a bad idea: block cipher key setup is supposed to be as fast as possible, while passphrases should be run through a KDF that is as slow as possible. This is only a weakness if you don't know what you're doing, but if you do know what you're doing then there's never a reason to use a key longer than 256 bits.

Padding oracle attacks have nothing to do with the choice of block cipher; any Rijndael-based cryptosystem vulnerable to that kind of attack would still be vulnerable if you substituted Blowfish.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I intend on using 10000 rounds of SHA3_512, 16384 rounds of PBKDF2 and then Scrypt with N=16384, r=16, p=4. I think that should be enough.

Comment: @HACKERALERT No. Use Argon2. Don't use some custom amalgamation of KDFs.

Comment: Oh, good idea, I thought about that but didn't know which one would be best. Argon2 or argon2i or argon2id? I would prefer security over speed. Thanks!

Comment: I've added more context to my question, if that helps.

Comment: Actually, I've solved my question from this answer: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/72416/when-to-use-argon2i-vs-argon2d-vs-argon2id/72437#72437. I'll probably use argon2d for max security, since the encryption will be done in a browser and side channels don't matter. Also, it's not a communication protocol, so there's no Blowfish risk. It's similar to a password manager in terms of how it functions.

Comment: Would keeping SHA3_512, PBKDF2, and Scrypt provide additional benefit, or should I scrap them all in favour of Argon2d?

Comment: @HACKERALERT Scrap them all in favor of Argon2. And I would recommend Argon2id, which is a hybrid of the two and is generally recommended for most applications.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I think I'll go with Argon2id, since I've looked into it and it seems it is a good blend of both.