# Does Argon2id provide less protection against side-channel attacks than Argon2i theoretically and/or practically?

Tags: side-channel-attack, argon2

LUKS 2 encryption uses Argon2i as the default PBKDF. As the key is used on each access, I guess side-channel attacks are a significant threat factor. However, as I'm not a cryptographer, I am not qualified to say but I'm still interested whether this choice has its grounds.

Specifically, I am not interested in whether Argon2i provides less protection against TMTO, but whether Argon2id provides less protection against side-channel attacks. Also, it is interesting whether using Argon2id is practically safe enough for situations in which side-channel attacks are the main threat factor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use Argon2i vs Argon2d vs Argon2id?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/72437/18298)

Comment: @kelalaka IMO the answer you mentioned doesn't entirely answer the question whether Argon2id lowers protection against side-channel attacks. From that answer you can see that it does offer some protection against side-channel attacks, but not whether that protection is theoretically and/or practically worse than Argon2i. Again i am not a cryptologist.

Comment: I think it does. $D$ for data dependent, $I$ for data independent, and $id$ uses both approaches. So in side-channel security $argon2d< argon2id<argon2i$

Comment: Read the dupe answer again, and carefully please!

Comment: I guess the key point here is "_In other words, a side-channel attack against Argon2id reduces its security to one-pass Argon2i._". So Argon2id doesn't seem completely safe against side-channel attacks.

Comment: Yes, that's it!

Comment: Though it's interesting to me why [HERE](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-irtf-cfrg-argon2-13#section-4) they say "_....or you consider side-channel attacks as viable threat, choose Argon2id_". Seems like authors believe Argon2id is preferred to Argon2i or at least practically secure enough, even with the reduced side-channel protection.

Comment: That is the first paragraph of the answer in rephrasing.